# expectExceptionMessageRegExp() function is deprecated in phpunit 9 . What's the other alternate function that i can use instead?

Tags: phpunit, version

Am getting below issue after switching phpunit version from 7.1  to 9.5.28
Failed asserting that exception of type "Error" matches expected exception "Exception".
expectExceptionMessageRegExp() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

expectExceptionMessageRegExp() is deprecated in PHPUnit 8 and will be removed in PHPUnit 9. Use expectExceptionMessageMatches() instead.

Example :

```
function testResponse(){
 $this->expectExceptionMessageRegExp("/Unable to emit response/");
}
```

Replace with :

```
function testResponse(){
  $this->expectExceptionMessageMatches("/Unable to emit response/");
}
```